# WebAPI wont return JSON from database

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Cant figure this one out. I thought it should be simple and straight forward. I am making a request from an angular2 app to my webapi server. The request reaches the action and experiance no issues retrieving the data from the database but no JSON data gets returned. I am monitoring it in my web console and the request is just constantly pending (No JSON being returned, or even status code).

Here is my code in my controller:

```
[Route("api/login")]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    ResourceService resourceSVC = new ResourceService();
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Login()
    {
        //List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        List<Resource> resources = new List<Resource>();
        resources = resourceSVC.GetUsers().ToList();
        return this.Ok(new { data = resources.ToArray() });
    }

    //public IEnumerable<Resource> Login()
    //{
    //    var resources = resourceSVC.GetUsers().Take(2).ToList();
    //    return resources;
    //}
}
```

You will see in my first action I created a dummy integer list (Commented out) and that sent back successfully as JSON, no problem. But as soon as I'm trying to send back a list of resources from the database I dont get any response JSON data. You will see there is another action below tring to implement the return type of `Ienumerable` of resource, same issue is occuring.

If I leave the request to run for about 5min Visual Studio hits a Break Mode where I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So `ResourceService.GetUsers()` throws. Dig into that code.

Comment: Ah ok that sent me in the right direction. It seems because I had `LazyLoading` on, with it turned off it sent back the list. thanx

Comment: It's not like lazy loading is known to throw that exception. There's something else going wrong there.

Comment: I think the data set being returned is rather large as there are multiple linked tables to my resources model, and multiple linked tables on those links. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075410/asp-net-mvc-webapi-ef-lazy-loading-forever-loading was a interesting read and made me realize building a performance driven API and loading all possible linked data to a object is not feasible.

Comment: return ViewModel object collection but not not mapper class - not sure if that is what you are doing from the example code.  No need to do ToArray it is a list and will be returned as array in json anyway. Just for the test create a list of Resource items and add some objects to it and then try to return it.